# Is there a good tutorial about Ninject + Repositories and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can somebody give me a link to good article about Ninject in ASP .NET MVC 3.0 with Repositories, Tests e.t.c.

Thx.

---

In my previous solution i worked with ControllerFactory:

**/Core/MvcFairyTaileControllerFactory.cs**

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbFairyTalesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    if (controllerType == null)
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    else
        return (Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, new DataManager(connectionString)) as IController);
}
```

I had DataManager class:

**/Models/DataManager.cs**

```
public class DataManager
{
    private MvcFairyTalesDataContext _MvcFairyTalesDataContext;
    public DataManager(string connectionString)
    {
        _MvcFairyTalesDataContext = new MvcFairyTalesDataContext(connectionString);
    }

    private FairyTalesRepository _fairyTalesRepository;
    public FairyTalesRepository Tales
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fairyTalesRepository == null)
                _fairyTalesRepository = new FairyTalesRepository(_MvcFairyTalesDataContext);

            return _fairyTalesRepository;
        }
    }

    private CategoriesRepository _categoriesRepository;
    public CategoriesRepository Categories
    {
        get
        {
            if (_categoriesRepository == null)
                _categoriesRepository = new CategoriesRepository(_MvcFairyTalesDataContext);

            return _categoriesRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

And there is my CategoriesRepository

**/Models/CategoriesRepository.cs**

```
public class CategoriesRepository
{
    private MvcFairyTalesDataContext _dataContext;

    public CategoriesRepository(MvcFairyTalesDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
    {
        return _dataContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.NameAn);
    }
}
```

And in my Controllers, i can work with repositories like this:

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Categories/
    private DataManager _dataManager;
    public CategoriesController(DataManager dataManager)
    {
        _dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Categories"] = _dataManager.Categories.GetAllCategories();
        return View();
    }
}
```

So, i think this is not very good solution, and i'd like to rewrite this in Ninject + MVC 3.0.

---

**Updated:**

Now i have something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterDependencyResolver();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterDependencyResolver()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<IDataManager>().To<DataManager>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbFairyTalesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

My DataManager class is:

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager
{
    FairyTalesMVC3DataContext _dataContext;
    public DataManager(string connectionString)
    {
        _dataContext = new FairyTalesMVC3DataContext(connectionString);
    }

    private TalesRepository _talesRepository;
    public TalesRepository Tales
    {
        get
        {
            if (_talesRepository == null)
                _talesRepository = new TalesRepository(_dataContext);

            return _talesRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

But what should i write in IDataManager to return in controller "Tales"?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataManager _dataManager;

    public HomeController(IDataManager dataManager)
    {
        _dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = _dataManager.Tales.GetAllCategories().First().NameAn; // Tales not defined.

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one [blog post](http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html) you may take a look at. It illustrates how to use the new [IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver.aspx) with Ninject. And here's [another one](http://mrdustpan.blogspot.com/2010/12/ninject-with-aspnet-mvc-3easy-as-1-2-3.html) using the more standard `NinjectHttpApplication`.

As far as unit testing is concerned, this doesn't really has any relation to the DI framework you are using. As far as your repositories are properly abstracted with interfaces, testing your controllers is a matter of picking a mocking framework. Here's an [example with Rhino Mocks](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chrismissal/archive/2010/02/05/unit-testing-simple-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx).

[MvcContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) is also worth looking at as it would simplify your unit tests b y mocking all the HTTP context such as Request, Response, Session, ...

Comment: I still can't understand, how should i initialize my DataManager class with repositories, if i use repositories for work with my LINQ Data Context (something like GetAllOrders()) and my DataManager for links to this repositories (something like _dataManager.Orders.GetAllOrders()).

Comment: @user568262, what is this DataManager class that you are talking about? Maybe you could show some code? The idea is that all layers of your application should be weakly coupled. To achieve this weak coupling you define interfaces and implement those interfaces. Then you pass those interfaces to the constructors of other layers. Ninject is just used in the web tier to make the plumbing and say which implementation of the given interface to use. In the unit test you replace this implementation with Mock objects.

Comment: So, now i rewrite my solution to Ninject, but i can't understand, how should i return categoriesRepository from my IDataManager?

Comment: @user568262, everything in your code seems strongly coupled. Not a single interface. Without introducing interfaces and abstract your layers you will have hard time implementing DI and even harder to unit test.

Comment: Can u give me a link to article with well done structure of application? I really need this =\

Comment: @user568262, you may take a look at a sample MVC project structure I wrote: https://github.com/darind/samplemvc It uses Spring.NET for DI but this could be very easily substituted with any DI framework you like such as Ninject for example. You may also checkout the accompanying blog post: http://www.bratched.com/en/home/aspnet-mvc/62-how-we-do-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: @user568262, yes, there seems to be a problem with github at the moment. I've uploaded the source code here: http://www.mediafire.com/?70xcp954txxwpbj